# Regex: Matching words with special characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find a regular expression that matches a word in a string (the exact word). The problem is when this word has special characters like '#' or anything else. The special characters could be any UTF-8 char, like ("áéíóúñ#@"), and it have to ignore punctuations marks.

I put some examples of what i'm looking for:

```
Searching:#myword

 Sentence: "I like the elephants when they say #myword" <- MATCH
 Sentence: "I like the elephants when they say #mywords" <- NO MATCH
 Sentence: "I like the elephants when they say myword" <-NO MATCH
 Sentence: "I don't like #mywords. its silly" <- NO MATCH
 Sentence: "I like #myword!! It's awesome" <- MATCH
 Sentence: "I like #myword It's awesome" <- MATCH
```

PHP Example code:

```
 $regexp= "#myword";
    if (preg_match("/(\w$regexp)/", "I like #myword!! It's awesome")) {
        echo "YES YES YES";
    } else {
        echo "NO NO NO ";
    }
```

Thank you!

**Update:** If I look for "**myword**" the word has to begin by "w" and not another char.

```
Sentence: "I like myword!! It's awesome" <- MATCH
Sentence: "I like #myword It's awesome" <-NO MATCH
```

Comment: How does the 2nd and 4th produces a match and non match?

Comment: the 2nd it's followed by an alphabetical character and 4th isn't

Comment: try escaping special characters with \

Comment: Should both 'myword' and 'mywords' be matched? Your examples don't quite make sense.

Comment: Actually "s" is an alphabetical character that follows #myword in both no. 2 and no. 4.

Comment: @Mauritz you're right i misspelled, now the 5th example it's corrected

Comment: Provide a piece of your code, and everything will become clear

Comment: @Yaronius code in PHP provided, thank you ;)

Comment: Hm, maybe I'm missing something, but I wonder why do you need those brackets () in your pattern? You don't use variable grouping, do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution below is produced when thinking about characters and boundaries separately. There could also be a viable approach to use word boundaries directly.

Code:

```
function search($strings,$search) {
        $regexp = "/(?:[[:space:]]|^)".$search."(?:[^\w]|$)/i";
        foreach ($strings as $string) {
                echo "Sentence: \"$string\" <- " . 
                     (preg_match($regexp,$string) ? "MATCH" : "NO MATCH") ."\n";
        }
}

$strings = array(
"I like the elephants when they say #myword",
"I like the elephants when they say #mywords",
"I like the elephants when they say myword",
"I don't like #mywords. its silly",
"I like #myword!! It's awesome",
"I like #mywOrd It's awesome",
);
echo "Example 1:\n";
search($strings,"#myword");

$strings = array(
"I like myword!! It's awesome",
"I like #myword It's awesome",
);
echo "Example 2:\n";
search($strings,"myword");
```

Output:

```
Example 1:
Sentence: "I like the elephants when they say #myword" <- MATCH
Sentence: "I like the elephants when they say #mywords" <- NO MATCH
Sentence: "I like the elephants when they say myword" <- NO MATCH
Sentence: "I don't like #mywords. its silly" <- NO MATCH
Sentence: "I like #myword!! It's awesome" <- MATCH
Sentence: "I like #mywOrd It's awesome" <- MATCH
Example 2:
Sentence: "I like myword!! It's awesome" <- MATCH
Sentence: "I like #myword It's awesome" <- NO MATCH
```

Comment: NP, I was utterly confused at first, but when you cleaned up the question and examples it could be solved. :)

Comment: It's nice : ) How can I add case insensitive?

Comment: just add 'i' at the end of the regexp.

Comment: If i look for "myword" without the hashtag it matches for "#myword" too and it mustn't, please check the new examples on the update

Answer (score 1):

You should search `myword` with wordboundary like this `/\bmyword\b/`.
`#` itself is also a wordboundary so `/\b#myword\b/` dosen't work.
one idea was to escape unicode character with `\X` but this will create other problems.

```
/ #myword\b/
```

Comment: this expression matches with 3rd example and it mustn't

Comment: @LDK true \X is not a good idea to escape the unicode charater

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (replace "myword" with whatever you want to find):

```
^.*#myword[^\w].*$
```

If the match is a success then your word was found - otherwise it wasn't.

Comment: This expression it's wrong :( `preg_match(): Unknown modifier '\'`

Comment: Okay? Works fine for me (Expresso - .Net). So you can replace "\w" with the characters: [a-z][A-Z][0-9]

Comment: Or maybe you just need to escape the slash ("\\" instead of "\" I don't know in PHP).

Comment: It does not produce the desired result, but otherwise it should work when adding delimiters.

Comment: Yeah, it works fine. It's expected that you may have to tailor it to your (LDK's) specific implementation. Like I said I don't know PHP.

Comment: It explicitly requires a character that is not within the word character class, this does not match the first example. But could probably be solved. "/^.*#myword(?:[^\w]|$)/i"

Comment: @Josh: That’s not a slash, it’s a backslash.

Comment: @Peter - oops, I missed that part. @tchrist - what are you referring to?